# How to pass process dir in runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problem to pass process dir. i want to spawn mongod process. application build with pkg. i tested to access without spawn section. like `console.log(args[1])`. it return dir process. after i uncomment that it said line 4

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'process' before initialization

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { parse } = require('path')

const processPath = parse(process.argv[0]);
const processDir = processPath.dir;

const executableName = 'mongod';
const args = [
    '-f', `${__dirname}/configs/mongodb.yml`,
    '--dbpath', `${processDir}/database/data`,
    '--logpath', `${processDir}/database/log/system.log`,
];
const options = {
    cwd: `${processDir}/bin`
};

const process = spawn(executableName, args, options);
process.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
})
```

my build dir, inside bin theres mongod executable.

```
build
build/program.exe
build/bin
build/database
build/database/data
build/database/log/system.log
```

i seperate assets that not include into real device filesystem. the rest inside snapshot filesystem (pkg virtual filesystem)

Comment: You have `const process = spawn(executableName, args, options);` further down. You need to rename that because it is shadowing the actual `process` global and causing the error.

Comment: @ChrisG ow, because of that. my IDE not showing error. i got new problem, mongod not launch inside program process. i test anything from spawn options like `detached`. no mongod process spawn. i test directly from script to change with `__dirname` before compile. it can spawn mongod. after compile with pkg. it just print out success.

Comment: @ChrisG this the link, exactly the code similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210212/spawn-process-inside-process-or-detached-it-pkg-builder

Comment: @ChrisG after i test, spawn cant read pkg file system. exactly i want to hide the config. but i dont to solve it. so far what i think, read config from pkg file system to device filesystem.