# Spawn process inside process or detached it pkg builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I dont sure what the problem here, mongod process not spawn inside program.exe that create with pkg. i test it first before compile the script can launch mongod process. after i tested it, spawn cant read pkg filesystem ( snapshot ).

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { parse } = require('path')

let processPath = parse(process.argv[0]);
let processDir = processPath.dir;

const args = [
    '-f', `${__dirname}\\configs\\mongodb.yml`,
    '--dbpath', `${processDir}\\database\\data`,
    '--logpath', `${processDir}\\database\\log\\system.log`,
];
const options = {
    cwd: `${processDir}\\bin`
};

const mongod = spawn('mongod', args, options);
mongod.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
});
mongod.stdout.on('error', chunk => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
});
mongod.on('spawn', () => {
    console.log('success')
});
mongod.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Build Dir

```
build
build/program.exe
build/bin
build/bin/mongod.exe
build/database
build/database/data
build/database/log/system.log
```

Package.json pkg configurations

```
"bin": "dist/application.js",
  "pkg": {
    "targets": ["node16-win-x64"],
    "outputPath": "dist/build",
    "assets": [
      "dist/configs/*"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: No idea tbh, maybe you need to move mongod.exe into the assets folder? You may have to switch to a file-based database like sqlite.

Comment: @ChrisG Pkg make a virtual file system. ex, device file system is `c:/project`. while compile with pkg. it will add snapshot before project `c:/snapshot/project`. the problem spawn cant read directly mongodb config that add into assets to access pkg file system. it uses `__dirname`. cause it virtual only exist in runtime. in 1st args. spawn cant read that config.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this issue, tested on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

**Case scenario:**
I needed to include an executable file `hello_world` as an asset into `/snapshot/project/bin/hello_world` virtual path and based on some conditions execute it inside the Linux environment.

**The problem:**
I was getting the following error when I've been trying to execute the command via `child_process.spawn`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /snaponshot/project/bin/hello_world: not found
```

So clearly my OS is trying to execute `hello_world` command via `/bin/sh`, however, the system is unable to access to `/snapshot` virtual filesystem, therefor not able to execute it.

**The workaround:**
Clearly, the main file system is unable to access the virtual file system, but we can do the opposite, by copying our executable file from the virtual file system into the main file system and executing it from there, basically, this is what I did:

```js
//node packages
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const {execSync, spawn} = require('child_process');

// executable file name
const executable = 'hello_world';

//file path to the asset executable file
const remoteControlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `../bin/${executable}`);

let executableFileFullPath = remoteControlFilePath;
// avoid the workaround if the parent process in not pkg-ed version.
if (process.pkg) {
  // creating a temporary folder for our executable file
  const destination = fs.mkdtempSync(`${os.tmpdir()}${path.sep}`);
  const destinationPath = path.join(destination, executable);
  executableFileFullPath = destinationPath;
  // copy the executable file into the temporary folder
  fs.copyFileSync(remoteControlFilePath, destinationPath);

  // on Linux systems you need to manually make the file executable
  execSync(`chmod +x ${destinationPath}`);
}

// using {detached: true}, execute the command independently of its parent process
// to avoid the main parent process' failing if the child process failed as well.
const child = spawn(executableFileFullPath, {detached: true});
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
});
child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`child stderr:\n${data}`);
});
child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}`);
});
```

Comment: worked on macos darwin x86!